# Egit classes get greyed out

Tags: java, eclipse, push, egit

Eclipse greys out new added classes, so EGit doesn't stash them as changes.
[image]

Comment: It looks like you are using the Darkest Dark theme which has "special" icons and colors. Could you please share a screenshot of the default theme that also includes the project folder? Is this the _Package/Project Explorer_ view?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It seems like my .gitgnore file was messy. So I deleted it and do "Add to index".